# Is There An Easy Way To Comment Out XAML Code in Microsoft Blend?

Tags: html, xaml, comments, blend

I've been using Blend 4 for a while, especially when customizing templates, and one thing irks me.  There's no 'comment' button, so I can't easily wrap a highlighted section of XAML with HTML comments (`<!-- -->`).

Is there any workaround for this, or am I forever stuck having to type those.

NOTE: I did see a macro extension that allows you to open/close comment with a shortcut key, but sadly it doesn't install with my version of Blend.

Comment: Can you share the link to this Macro extension?

Comment: @Dai Here's the link to the extension: http://blendshortcuts.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

Keyboard:  CTRL + K, CTRL + C (comment)
           CTRL + K, CTRL + U (uncomment)

Menu:  Edit -> Advanced -> Comment Selection 
       Edit -> Advanced -> Uncomment Selection

Answer (score 1):

Try

View-->Toolbars-->Text Editor

Would add the toolbar that has comment out and uncomment buttons.

Have a blessed day!